# Subquery to sum values from a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, subquery

I use this code to sum an order for a certain date:

```
select od.OrderID, (od.unitprice * quantity) - ((od.unitprice * od.quantity) * discount) + freight as OrderSum
from orders, [Order Details] as od
where orderdate = '1996-12-12' and od.orderid = orders.orderid
```

The code above gives the following output table:

```
OrderID | OrderSum
10380     370,37
10380     506,63
10381     119,99
```

Desired end result and output: I want to sum the values in the created column "OrderSum" above so that the output would be put in a column named "Total ordersum". In other words, the desired output table I actually want:

```
Total ordersum
996,99
```

How can I add a subquery to the code above to solve this? I would be very thankful if someone could give a code sample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do an aggregation query:

```
select sum(od.unitprice * quantity) - sum((od.unitprice * od.quantity) * discount) + sum(freight) as Total_OrderSum
from orders o join
     [Order Details] as od
     on od.orderid = o.orderid
where orderdate = '1996-12-12';
```

Note:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use explicit `JOIN` syntax with the conditions in the `ON` clause.

Comment: Is there any performance difference between using sum(<all the content of the OrderSum column in the old query>)  and using three different sum calls as you are using in your answer ?

Comment: @Egl . .  I don't think there is much difference in performance.